# Trouble installing kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I've been trying to install Kivy on ubuntu for python 3.
For my first attempt I followed the instructions on this page "https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html" which seemed to work but when I tried using running a program to test it I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kivytest.py", line 1, in <module>
    from kivy.app import App
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy'
```

Afterwards I attempted to install it with pip, in which I got the errors:

```
Failed building wheel for kivy
```

And it told me my cython is version 0.25, which might be incompatible, so I should install 0.23 with:

```
pip install -I Cython==0.23
```

Which I also tried to do, but I got the error:

```
Failed building wheel for Cython
```

If I could get some help getting kivy installed and working correctly that would be awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is with conflicting dependencies. It's always better to work in a virtual environment. I would suggest you use `pipenv`, this is a tested method for using Kivy and I can verify it. I have been using `pipenv` for the development of my [GSoC project](https://salsa.debian.org/new-contributor-wizard-team/new-contributor-wizard) and it works like a charm. So here's what you have to do.

Assuming you have pip (or pip3 for python3) installed

```
pip install pipenv
pipenv python 3.5
pipenv install cython==0.28
pipenv install kivy==1.10.1
```

Now, test the installation

```
pipenv run python
>>> from kivy.uix.button import Button
```

If you get a lot  of `[info]` messages on prompt like

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/realslimshanky/.kivy/logs/kivy_18-07-21_0.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.0.dev0, git-1828af3, 20180623
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.5.3 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:11:04) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170118]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
```

Then this means the installation has been successful. You're free to hack your way to a cool project now! ;)